# How do you set the default scroll of an MS access listbox to be top

Tags: ms-access, listbox, default

I have a multi-select listbox on MS access form 2010, i have a routine which selects default values like this

```
 For i = 0 To CategoriesList.ListCount - 1
If InStr(1, ",2,3,17,6,22,13,10,48,39,18,", ("," & CategoriesList.ItemData(i) & ",")) Then
CategoriesList.Selected(i) = True
End If
Next i
```

which works perfectly,
now the thing is that the listbox has the height of only three items, and it has 48 iems total, once i do the above routine, the list box shows the last three items be default (scrolls to bottom)

how do i make the listbox scroll to top by default?

Answer (score 2):

To do this, without having to set the focus to the listbox, loop through the list items in reverse.  Since the code will end on the first item, the listbox will be scrolled to the top:

```
    For i =  (CategoriesList.ListCount - 1) to 0 Step -1
    If InStr(1, ",2,3,17,6,22,13,10,48,39,18,", ("," & CategoriesList.ItemData(i) & ",")) Then
    CategoriesList.Selected(i) = True
    End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the `ListIndex` to 1 (the first item) but it requires the listbox to have focus:

```
Me.List6.Selected(8) = True
Me.List6.Selected(9) = True
Me.List6.SetFocus
Me.List6.ListIndex = 1
```

If you set the ListIndex to the first found item (i) then it will make this the top (displayed) item in the list.